# Not able to switch to beta channel in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-web

Not able to switch to flutter beta channel
C:\Users\vairo_drrrnuo\IdeaProjects\bridge>flutter channel beta

```
Switching to flutter channel 'beta'...
git: From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
git:    f994b7697..9b9b543d9  beta                   -> origin/beta
git:  + cb8832388...7cd39d661 dds_integration_take_2 -> origin/dds_integration_take_2  (forced update)
git:    15a28159b..c68758fab  master                 -> origin/master
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-4.2.pre         -> 1.19.0-4.2.pre
git: error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
git:    examples/flutter_view/ios/Podfile
git:    packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/base/platform.dart
git: Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
git: Aborting
Switching channels failed with error code 1.
```

Comment: how to retrive those files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to flutter directory and then open a terminal  type this **git clean -xffd**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that two files of your project have been changed which cause problems when changing the channel:

- examples/flutter_view/ios/Podfile
- packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/base/platform.dart

Furthermore, both files do not appear to be indexed in the git repository. So you now have the following options:

1. **change out of your project folder into an irrelevant directory and try running `flutter channel beta` again.** (Probably the easiest solution)
2. delete the two files if you don't need them (ios/Podfile is usually needed to compile for iOS)
3. add the files to your git repo, run `git comit` and run it again

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)